# Parse 'family' names into people + last name with regex

Tags: regex, text-parsing, data-entry

Given the following string, I'd like to parse into a list of first names + a last name:

> Peter-Paul, Mary & Joël Van der Winkel

(and the simpler versions)

I'm trying to work out if I can do this with a regex. I've got this far

```
(?:([^, &]+))[, &]*(?:([^, &]+))
```

But the problem here is that I'd like the last name to be captured in a different capture.

I suspect I'm beyond what's possible, but just in case...

**UPDATE**

Extracting captures from the group was new for me, so here's the (C#) code I used:

```
string familyName = "Peter-Paul, Mary & Joël Van der Winkel";
string firstperson = @"^(?<First>[-\w]+)"; //.Net syntax for named capture
string lastname = @"\s+(?<Last>.*)";
string others = @"(?:(?:\s*[,|&]\s*)(?<Others>[-\w]+))*";

var reg = new Regex(firstperson + others + lastname);
var groups = reg.Match(familyName).Groups;
Console.WriteLine("LastName=" + groups["Last"].Value);
Console.WriteLine("First person=" + groups["First"].Value);
foreach(Capture firstname in groups["Others"].Captures)
    Console.WriteLine("Other person=" + firstname.Value);
```

I had to tweak the accepted answer slightly to get it to cover cases such as:

> Peter-Paul&Joseph Van der Winkel
>
> Peter-Paul  &  Joseph  Van der Winkel

Comment: I can't see from your question if these names are guaranteed to be normalized, but what about a name like Peter Paul van der Winkel? (i.e., no hyphen, and Dutch rather than Flemish/English capitalization rules.)

Comment: Good question. I'm not trying to be too clever here. In this case, if the result says firstname = Peter and lastname = Paul van der Winkel, I don't mind. The aim is to have a 'quick and rough' way to enter contact details; the user can always fall back on entering fields separately.

Comment: Updated with the regex for my answer.

Comment: Checkout `humanparser` on NPM https://www.npmjs.org/package/humanparser

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming a first name can not be two words with a space (otherwise Peter Paul Van der Winkel is not automatically parsable), then the following set of rules applies:

- (first name), then any number of (, first name) or (& first name)
- Everything left is the last name.

  ```
  ^([-\w]+)(?:(?:\s?[,|&]\s)([-\w]+)\s?)*(.*)
  ```

Answer (score 1):

Seems that this might do the trick:

```
((?:[^, &]+\s*[,&]+\s*)*[^, &]+)\s+([^,&]+)
```